# Getting Started and Paypal Integration (C#)

Tags: paypal

I am using MVC and C# with a custom cart and I am trying to integrate into paypal. I have been getting lost in the so many different options with paypal. Is there a simple resource explaining the basics? I tried using the code below and it fails but there is no error code. I do not really understand how the integration works and the documentation covers so many different arrangements I am finding it is fairly hard. Paypal said I should post in this forum.

```
 string authToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDTToken"];
        //read in txn token from querystring
        string txToken = Request.QueryString.Get("tx");

        string query = string.Format("cmd=_notify-synch&tx={0}&at={1}",
                              txToken, authToken);
        // Create the request back
        string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrl"];
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        // Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = query.Length;
        // Write the request back IPN strings
        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),
                                 System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(query);
        stOut.Close();
        // Do the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
        stIn.Close();
        if (strResponse.StartsWith("SUCCESS"))
        {
            PDTHolder pdt = PDTHolder.Parse(strResponse);
            return pdt;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

My Web.Config is all correct and in debugging the url seems correct but it just responds "FAIL" with no more details.

Has anyone any ideas? The desired system will be the user adds to cart and then clicks Order, then the system takes the user to paypal.com and that takes the payment followed by a return to my site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .net SDK for paypal:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK

the readme contains links to a TON of tutorials and sample code for usage in c#.

Comment: Just to update readers, paypal actually have a support service (unknown to me before) and they apparently offer help. I am now using this.